# Convert spreadsheet data to 2sxc data items

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a spreadsheet of data that I would like to convert to 2sxc data items.

Are there any tools or suggested approaches to doing this?  (I can get the data into a SQL table if that would help.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you can import and export data type and items to and from XML.